# Does the browser still stores the website you visited Private Browsing [incognito Firefox]?

Tags: web-browser, privacy, firefox

As they clearly state in their website they mention that

**What does Private Browsing not save?**

- Visited pages: No pages will be added to the list of sites in the
  History menu, the Library window's history list, or the Awesome Bar
  address list.
- Cached Web Content and Offline Web Content and User Data: No temporary Internet files (cached files) or files that websites save for offline use will be saved.

Considering this Scenario

If I open a tab in *incognito Mode* as per below screenshot.
[image]

After I close the tab It gives me an option to *Undo Close Tab* and If I click on it,This restores the tab which I closed.!
[image]

*So Does this mean that this statement is untrue?*
**Cached Web Content and Offline Web Content and User Data: No temporary Internet files (cached files) or files that websites save for offline use will be saved**

***Further research regarding this***
I opened the `about:config` from Firefox and I filtered `browser.sessionstore`.and I'm setting the following preferences as follows,and now closed tab will no longer will be able to perform **undo**

- browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo;0
- browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo;0

[image]

**According to Firefox**

> The saved session data is also cleared upon receiving the
>   "browser:purge-session-history" notification.
>
> The data is stored on disk as a serialized javascript data structure
>   (though it's possible that it will be converted to JSON once that
>   becomes natively supported by Gecko/Spidermonkey)

Comment: I would be willing to bet that the entire tab object is saved in memory until the browser is closed.  This wouldn't be on disk, but if the user chooses "undo" it can be restored.

Comment: Firefox isn't Chrome - different tabs are *not* different processes. There's no guarantee that every individual private tab is separate; the guarantee applies to the session as a whole (just like all browsers support the back button in incognito)

Comment: @raz. Unfortunately that is not true.Did bit of research regarding this and edited my question

Comment: @PathumAnjana Close all private tabs and windows and open again. Can you undo close tabs to bring up the previous session?

Comment: @muru No,I'm aware that everything is erased when I close the browser

Comment: @PathumAnjana not the entire browser session. Just the private tabs.

Comment: @muru The Last Closed Tab Opens-up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not untrue but IS possibly misleading.

Certainly files are in fact cached while the in-private session is active, they are then cleared at the end. Of course, we all know this could leave a footprint.

In-private sessions are not really meant to prevent someone from discovering a footprint but more to prevent inadvertent "bleed" between sessions.

Comment: I can agree with your answer ;)